# superclass mismatch for class Address braintree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, payment, braintree

i just installed the braintree payment gem and now i'm receiving a error on a page that was working previously. i have a model named Address.

```
superclass mismatch for class Address
```

is this expected because braintree has a class named Address as well? how would i work around it/fix it?

i'm using the latest braintree gem (v2.25), ruby 2.0 on rails 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I had 2 versions of Braintree installed (2.16 and 2.25). After uninstalling the older one, I no longer receive the error.

Answer (score 2):

You're correct. The Braintree gem has a class Address. However, the Address class is inside of the Braintree module. Since it is inside of a module, your class should not conflict with it. Unless of course, your Address class is also inside of a module named Braintree. You should see this sort of behavior in irb:

```
module Braintree
    class Address
    end
end

module MyModule
    class Address < String #Or ActiveRecord::Base or any class
    end
end
```

Should work just fine, since your address is in a different module. However, if they are in the same module:

```
module Braintree
    class Address
    end
end

module Braintree
    class Address < String #Or ActiveRecord::Base or any class
    end
end
```

You will see an error similar to what you posted above.

So your options are to make sure that your Address class is named uniquely, or ensure that it is inside of a different module and you are referring to the correct Address object whenever you refer to one.

Comment: my address class is not inside any module. just a plain address class. class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user  
  has_many :shippings
  has_many :orders
  belongs_to :state
  has_many :cards
  
  validates :street, presence: true
  validates :city, presence: true
  validates :state_id, presence: true
  validates :zip, presence: true
  
end
and i don't want to put it in a module. does that mean i have to change my Address class name.